# How can represent JSON using a Codable struct if the keys are not defined?

Tags: json, swift, codable

I would like to represent the following JSON as a struct that conforms to `Codable`:

```
{
    "trooper": {"name": "Trooper", "type": "alsatian"},
    "spot": {"name": "Spot", "type": "labrador"},
    "sniffles": {"name": "Sniffles", "type": "poodle"}
}
```

The list is not exhaustive i.e. there can be any number of dogs in the list.

The `{"name": "Sniffles", "type": "poodle"}` part is easy, and can be done like this:

```
struct Dog: Codable {
    var name: String
    var type: String
}
```

But what about the root level?

Comment: Thanks for pointing to that possible duplicate. That would work too but I found a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I was looking for:

```
let str = """
{
    "trooper": {"name": "Trooper", "type": "alsatian"},
    "spot": {"name": "Spot", "type": "labrador"},
    "sniffles": {"name": "Sniffles", "type": "poodle"}
}
"""

struct Dog: Codable {
    var name: String
    var type: String
}

if let data = str.data(using: .utf8) {

    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let dogs = try decoder.decode([String: Dog].self, from: data)
        print(dogs)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

}
```